# Disable text output on startup?

Tags: boot, grub2, burg

So I have a Ubuntu 15.10 machine with burg installed. Now when I start my machine and select Ubuntu from burg, before Ubuntu loads, some text output is shown on the screen. Now I don't know what this text is, but I would like to disable the text output and replace it with Ubuntu splash screen if possible. 
I have attached an image of the text output that is shown.
[image]

Also, I have attached the links to my `/etc/default/burg` and `/etc/default/grub` files:

`burg`: [/etc/default/burg](http://pastebin.ca/3307077)

`grub`: [/etc/default/grub](http://pastebin.ca/3307078)

Edit 1: I forgot to say that I don't think this has anything to do with `burg`, as I got the same text output even when I was using `grub`

Edit 2: BUMP